# What is difference between for and .map in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, for-loop

I have some codes:

```
 const moves = history.map((step, move) => {
      const desc = move ?
        'Go to move #' + move :
        'Go to game start';
      return (
        <li key={move}>
           <BtnMove desc={desc} onClick={() => this.jumpTo(move)} className={this.state.classNames[move]}/>
        </li>
      );
    });
```

and:

```
 
    var moves = []
    for(var move = 0; move < history.length; move++){
      const desc = move ?
        'Go to move #' + move :
        'Go to game start';
      moves.push(<li key={move}>
           <BtnMove desc={desc} onClick={() => this.jumpTo(move)} className={this.state.classNames[move]}/>
        </li>)
      
    }
```

When I call function **jumpTo(move)** with first code is fine, but with second code will throw error because ***move* is greater than *history.length***.
I need for loops on my program. Please help me!

Comment: What is the value of history.length?

Comment: try after change var to let

Comment: Example: history.length is 4, then jumpTo(move = 5)

Comment: I change var to let, it same error

Comment: I believe that change `var` to `let` in for loop will at least throw another error.

Comment: Provide more code for ease of getting help, why you need `for` instead of `map` ?

Comment: @thelonglqd: you can find full code at: https://codepen.io/thinhtpq/pen/qBajZer. Click on the square -> Click button "Go to move #1", then you will see error

Comment: @ThinhTran: I got this error instead `TypeError: Cannot read property 'squares' of undefined`

Comment: @thelonglqd: Yes, that's it. Because 'step' is greater than length of 'squares' array now. You will see value of 'step' on alert when you click button.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using var (moves, move), here is a working sample with for loop:
https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-golick-r917t?file=/src/App.js
I just replaced your jumpTo with a simple alert function

Comment: Oh. I don't see any for loop. It's just .map function